# Shortest cost word transformation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

I am trying to solve the following question.

You are given a starting word, a dictionary and an ending word. You can perform 4 operations.

1. Add a letter at any position
2. Delete a letter at any position
3. Replace a letter at any position
4. Take anagram of word(cat can be changed to act).

All the costs of these operations may be different and are given too.

Constraint : all intermediate letters along with starting word and ending word has to be present in the dictionary. Find the minimum possible cost to achieve this.

If there is no way return -1;

Any Ideas please ?

Comment: "All the costs...may be different, and are given"
I feel like this increases the complexity of the problem too much. If all the costs were 1, then I'd know where to start here.

Comment: Sounds like a simple shortest path search on a graph where the vertices are the words in the dictionary and the weighted edges are the operations leading from one word to the other.

Comment: Thanks Henry. I have tried in Java and each insert, delete, replace(since strings are immutable) takes O(S) where S is length of string and doing it any index makes it O(S^2) for every word. I tried this algorithm(Dijkstra)  it is not giving any results at least in 20 minutes. I am sure there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should tell me more details about constraints(like maximum length of words or maximum number of words in dictionary).

But I'll tell you one solution to solve that problem.

First, you can make graph. Each node is a word you can make(in dictionary) and edge is operation that you can do.

Every edge has weight which is given from input. Then you should save the distance from starting word to every other words in dictionary. In C++, you can declare `map<string, int>`.

The key of that map is the node string and the value of that map is the distance from initial word.

Then you can use shortest distance algorithms like dijkstra. Starting point is initial word and finishing point is a word we wanna make. Because Dijkstra is the fastest algorithm with one starting point in usual, I'll use it if I were you.

Then, let's calculate time complexity.

Let's say the maximum length of every word is S and the maximum number of words in dictionary is N.

In every operation, it takes O(S) if you change positions of some characters or add or remove a character in some position except back of the word and O(1) if you just change a character.

Anyways the total time complexity is O(SNlgN) cuz the maximum number of nodes in our graph is the maximum number of words in dictionary cuz if there are any words in dictionary which we can make from the word we have now, then we can no longer make edge from current node.

And the maximum number of edges is O(N) cuz we can make 4 edges in every nodes at most. So if you know the time complexity of Dijkstra with heap, it's simple.

Comment: Thanks David.. In the problem statement I am not given any constraint about the maximum length of words or maximum number of words in the dictionary. Also, in Java specifically each insert, delete, replace(since strings are immutable) takes O(S) where S is length of string and doing it any index makes it O(S^2) for every word. I tried this algorithm in Java its not giving any results at least in 20 minutes. I am sure there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should tell me more detail about constraint(like maximum length of words or maximum number of words in dictionary).
But I'll tell you some ways to solve that problem.
First, you can make graph. Each node is a word you can make(in dictionary) and edge is operation that you can do. Every edge has weight which is given from input. In C++, you can declare map`<string, int>`. The key of that map is the node string and the value of that map is the distance from initial word.
Then you can use shortest distance algorithms like dijkstra. Because Dijkstra is the fastest algorithm with one starting point in usual, I'll use it if I were you. Then, let's calculate time complexity. Let's say the maximum length of every word is S and the maximum number of words in dictionary is N. In every operation, it takes O(S) if you might change positions of some characters or add or remove a character in some position except back of the word